# Android ActivityCompat

Tags: android, android-permission, file-permission

Olá pelo que eu pesquisei a partir do android 7.1, é necessário solicitar permissão em execução para usuário e é necessário usar a classe `ActivityCompat` para tal feito, minha aplicação salva um PDF no disco e abre ela, contudo não consigo usar essa classe `ActivityCompat` ocorre erro de compilação. Estou importando da v4 e usando eclipse ainda, é isso mesmo? Já tentei importar do `import android.support.v7.*;` contudo não aparece essa classe nesse pacote.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
     ActivityCompat().requestPermissions(this, new {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
```

Comment: Na verdade as runtime permissions começam a partir do Android 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converte o app para android studio e funcionou o eclipse não dá mais pra trabalhar é muitos bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> ActivityCompat().requestPermissions(...);

Use o método estático da classe `ActivityCompat`, você colocou parênteses, sendo assim o compilador está esperando uma método local que não existe.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
```